Cantor's paradox and the universal set
I came across this in a philosophy book on sets:


My issues regarding the first paragraph:
Should the fourth sentence not start with “Now we show u = $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{u})$” instead of “Now we show x = $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{u})$”? Furthermore, as far as I understand the universal set it contains everything, not just all sets but also things that cannot be reduced to sets (say chairs). But if that is the case, the proof in the first paragraph just does not work in my opinion. i) of the proof is trivial, I agree. But ii) presupposes that any element x of the universal set u has itself members and therefore is a set. Initially I thought plain natural numbers (also included in u) would count as counterexamples as well but I guess it is assumed that those are to be reduced to sets. Apart from my worries about the correctness of the proof. What is u usually thought to contain? Just sets (and numbers thought as sets) or non-sets as well?
As for the second paragraph:
c as a set is assumed to be a member of $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{u})$. But then the members of c themselves have to be member of u and I do not see why these members in see should be sets? If things other than sets are allowed in u, I again do not see how the proof of ii) in the first paragraph is supposed to work.
What am I missing?
Addendum:
The presentation of Cantor's paradox in the book I am quoting appears in a section about naive set theory and the naive comprehension axiom. Furthermore, the author defines sets the page before:

Definition 11 (Informal) The naive conception of set holds that sets
are extensions of predicates, where the extension of a predicate is
the collection of all the things to which the predicate applies

Why he then presents Cantor's paradox with a proof that assumes a refined conception of sets, I don't know.

"Should the fourth sentence [...]" yes, that is a rather obvious typo. As for "what does $u$ contain," this is (hopefully) resolved by looking up what the author means by ${x \mid P(x)}$, but from the context of the proof it seems rather likely that they are only considering sets, and further that members of a set are again sets.

@BenSteffan Is that the canonical interpretation of the universal set u, meaning that sets are the only things there are? And did Cantor think of numbers or whatever can be a member of a set as sets themselves? Does Cantor's paradox only arise in a world that only consists of sets?

@BenSteffan I was lazy with latex. There is no P(x) only the powerset $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{x})$

Oh, the $P(x)$ in ${x \mid P(x)}$ is supposed to just be some predicate, sorry for the confusion. I'm asking you to look up what this (set-builder) notation means in the book you're reading. In any case, universal set generally means "set of all objects of the theory." What that means depends on the theory you're considering. Working mathematicians generally assume that all objects are sets (although a host of caveats apply here), I'll also refer to this Wikipedia section

Of what Cantor thought I do not know, but I do think the paradox should concern the set of all sets, rather, whether this be the universal set or not. Whether this is described by the expression ${x \mid x = x}$ is a question of how your axioms are set up.

@BenSteffan I am not the smartest, so please forgive me being slow. I did not understand your second to last comment ("Oh,..."). There is no predicate $P$ only powersets. And I hope I have corrected any notational mistakes in my part of the original post. Apologies for those mistakes! What do you mean by "what this (set-builder) notation means". Which part of the text from the book needs clarifying in your opinion? Unfortunately the book jumps around a bit. I can send you a link to the pdf if you let me know.

The proof says that $u$ should be ${x \mid x = x}$. This is an instance of a form of notation we usually call set-builder notation: Using the same notation, you can for instance define the set of all even natural numbers ${n \mid \exists m \in \mathbb{N}\colon n = 2m}$. This is of the general form ${n \mid P(n)}$ where $P(n)$ is the predicate $P(n) = (\exists m \in \mathbb{N}\colon n = 2m)$. As for all notation, its meaning has to be defined somewhere. I'm asking you to look up what the book you're reading says this general notation means.

For instance, it could say that ${x \mid P(x)}$ means the set of all sets $x$ such that $P(x)$ is true, or it could say that it means the set of all $x$ (sans specifier, so objects) such that $P(x)$ is true. If it says the former, your problem disappears, because then $u$ is the set of all sets. If it is the latter, then this depends on what "object" means.

I think what the author wants to convey with {$x$$\vert x=x$} is just the set/predicate being identical to itself. And since everything is identical to itself, this predicate defines the universal set $u$. The author never distinguishes between "all sets x" and "all x". I am beginning to think that the writing is a bit sloppy.

In my answer, I show a definition from the same text that lends credibility to interpreting ${x|x=x}$ as a set of sets (containing no chairs or other non-set thing)

In an edition of the text this appears to be from, “Iterative Conceptions of Set,", this definition appears (emphasis mine):

Definition 13. The Naive Comprehension Schema asserts that for every
one place formula $\phi(x)$ in the language of set theory $L_\in$,
there is a set of all and only the sets satisfying $\phi(x)$.
Formally: $$(\exists y)( \forall z)\, \left(z\in y \leftrightarrow \phi(z)\right)$$


This suggests to me that $\{x | x=x\}$ (with $\phi(x)$ being the equality predicate and written out) is intended to contain only sets. The book doesn’t seem to define the notation $\{x | \phi(x)\}$, but having just mentioned “the set of [all] sets satisfying $\phi(x)$” one might guess that that thing (called $y$ in the definition) asserted to exist is notated as $\{x | \phi(x)\}$.

Thank you. I always thought that naive set theory allowed for non-sets as members and that only starting with ZFC we restrict objects of set theory to sets. In fact, wikipedia writes "In naive set theory, a set is described as a well-defined collection of objects. These objects are called the elements or members of the set. Objects can be anything: numbers, people, other sets, etc." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory#Sets,_membership_and_equality

@Max : “Pure” set theory, where everything is a set, seems to be what set theorists deal with most commonly. But you can also have set theory with non-sets as well as sets. The “non-sets” are usually called “atoms” or “urelements”. In that case one usually specifies up front what the “atoms” are going to be (maybe the real numbers, maybe the natural numbers, or whatever)
